# zeromq push-pull guaranteed delivery (re-transmit on error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

How can I fail a PULL to get retransmit from the pusher?

In the following example, if I uncomment the // throw ... to trigger an exception on every received message, all the PULL messages are failing, but when I put back the comment, all those messages are lost and not retransmitted by the pusher.

**How can I make sure the pusher will retransmit the messages if the PULL method fail?**

P.S. The following code is JavaScript in Meteor framework on top of nodejs, but it's not relevant to the problem as I suppose it's similar in every zmq implementations.

```
var zmq = Npm.require(modulePath + '/zmq');
var sock = zmq.socket('pull');
sock.identity = 'receiving' + process.pid;
sock.bind('tcp://172.17.4.25:5551', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err
    if (debug) console.log('Listening for ZMQ messages')
});

sock.on('message', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(data) {
    // throw { name: 'MessagePullFailed', message: 'Failing Pull message to check if ZMQ can recover from it' }
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(data)
    if (jsondata.cmd == 'upsert') {
        jsondata['set']['utctime'] = new Date(jsondata['set']['utctime'])
        Mon.upsert({_id: jsondata._id}, {'$set': jsondata['set']}, function(err) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
        })
    }
}))
```